# How can I find the response time (latency) of a client in NodeJS with sockets (socket.io)?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, latency

I'm trying to create a multiplayer game with NodeJS and I want to synchronize the action between clients.

What would be the best way to find the latency (the time that a request take to come back to the client) between the client and the server?

My first idea was that the client #1 could send a timestamp with is request, so when client #2 will receive the action of the client #1 he will adjust is action speed to remove the delay of the request.
But the problem is that maybe the system date time of the two clients are not identical so it is not possible two know the reel delay on the request of client #1.

The other solution was to use the timestamp of the server, but now how can I know the latency of a client?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using WebSockets or [Socket.IO](http://github.com/learnboost/socket.io-node) since you are implementing a game where latency matters (and you tagged it as such).

I would think the server should probably measure and keep track of this for each client.

You probably want to implement some sort of ping action that the server can request of the client. As soon as the client receives the request, it sends back a response to the server. The server then divides by 2 and updates the latency for that client. You probably want the server to do this periodically with each client and probably average the last several so that you don't get strange behavior from sudden but temporary spikes.

Then, when there is a message from one client that needs to be sent (or broadcast) to another client, the server can add client1's latency to client2's latency and communicate this as the latency offset to client2 as part of the message. client2 will then know that the event on client1 happened that many milliseconds ago.

An additional reason to do this on the server is that some browser Javascript timestamps are inaccurate: http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/. I suspect node.js timestamps are just as accurate (or more so) than V8 (which is one of the few accurate ones).

Comment: Yes i'm using "socket.io".  That exactly what I have implemented, the thing that I forget is to divide the latency by 2! Thanks for your advices!

Comment: Hey FR6, I actually just implemented a socket.io ping test because I too am interested in making web browser games using node.js as the server.  I'll write a blog post about it and link it here, hopefully it will help.  For some reason I've been getting ping times of about 220 ms on average for the websocket ping (roundtrip time) but

Comment: @FR6, @Travis: open source code (and blog) for this would be great. I'm sure lots of people will be interested in this going forward.

Comment: +1 for an exploration of this.  Would love to see some latency metrics and determine if response critical applications are finally possible in client side js (im thinking like button masher, street fighter style games and whatnot)

Answer (score 33):

## After reading all these answers...

...I still wasn't satisfied. I visited the official docs and well, well, well - the solution is already built-in.

You just need to implement it - check out mine:

### Client

```
// (Connect to socket).

var latency = 0;

socket.on('pong', function(ms) {
    latency = ms;

    console.log(latency);
});

// Do cool things, knowing the latency...
```

### Server

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);

// "socket.io": "^1.7.1"
// Set pingInterval to whatever you want - 'pong' gets emitted for you!
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {pingInterval: 5000});
```

Comment: This is the best and easiest answer.

Comment: Note that `pong` is deprecated in socket.io v3.0. More information [here](https://socket.io/docs/v3/migrating-from-2-x-to-3-0/#No-more-%E2%80%9Cpong%E2%80%9D-event-for-retrieving-latency).

Comment: @ItayGanor saved me the headache -- thank you

Answer (score 24):

### Overview:

After socket.io connection has been established, you create a new `Date` object on the client, let's call it `startTime`. This is your **initial time** before making a request to the server. You then emit a `ping` event from the client. Naming convention is totally up to you. Meanwhile server should be listening for a `ping` event, and when it receives the `ping`, it immediately emits a `pong` event. Client then catches the `pong` event. At this time you want to create another date object that represents `Date.now()`. So at this point you have two date objects - initial date before making a request to the server, and another date object after you make a request to the server and it replied. Subtract the `startTime` from current time and you have the `latency`.

### Client

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
var startTime;

setInterval(function() {
  startTime = Date.now();
  socket.emit('ping');
}, 2000);

socket.on('pong', function() {
  latency = Date.now() - startTime;
  console.log(latency);
});
```

### Server

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('ping', function() {
    socket.emit('pong');
  });
});
```

Also available as a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/sahat/8364120).

Comment: This adds another callback on the 'pong' every 2 seconds. The socket.on('pong' stuff should be outside the setInterval.

Comment: @PanMan silly mistake on my part, thanks for catching it.

Comment: `startTime` needs to be global for the code to work, just fyi :)  Thank you for this though.

Comment: For me, using the word 'ping' didn't work. I think it already be used by node.js. I changed it to something different and it worked.

Comment: NOTICE: ping and pong as message name is already used by socket.io itself https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 6):

What I usually do to send timestamp with request:

1. On the client, create a `new Date()` and send `timestamp: date.getTime()` to the server, with every JSON request.
2. On the server, upon receiving a request, put a `processed: (new Date()).getTime()` in the object.
3. Handle request.
4. On the response, put the `timestamp` from the request, and a new processed field: `processed: (new Date()).getTime() - req.processed` that now contains the number of milliseconds it took to process the request.
5. On the client, when receiving a response, take the `timestamp` (which is the same that was sent on pt 1) and subtract it from the current time, and subtract processing time (`processed`), and there is your "real" ping time in milliseconds.

I think you should always include the time for both request and response in the ping time, even if there is one-way communication. This is because that is the standard meaning behind "ping time" and "latency". And if it is one-way communication and the latency is only half of the real ping time, that's just a "good thing".

Comment: This is what I done in the first time.  But what does not work is that the client #1 and the client #2 maybe don't have the same date time (on different timezone) or are not synchronized.  And like kanaka was saying is that the JavaScript date time is maybe not accurate on the client side.

Comment: Whether or not it is accurate has nothing to do with anything. Each client (or server) only ever uses a date that that instance creates. The timestamp that is sent on request, is returned to the client exactly as it was. And so the client can see how long it was since the request was sent, in its own time.

Comment: Makes sense to me. It prevents you from having to make a separate 'ping' call between other calls. Is there a way of getting socket.io to include this automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Heres my really quick and dirty script to test the ping ... just head to http://yourserver:8080 in your browser and watch the console (ssh terminal for me).

```
var http = require('http');
var io = require('socket.io');

server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write('<html>\n');
  res.write('  <head>\n');
  res.write('    <title>Node Ping</title>\n');
  res.write('    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>\n');
  res.write('    <script>\n');
  res.write('        var socket = new io.Socket();\n');
  res.write('        socket.on("connect",function(){ });\n');
  res.write('        socket.on("message",function(){ socket.send(1); });\n');
  res.write('        socket.connect();\n');
  res.write('    </script>\n');
  res.write('  </head>\n');
  res.write('  <body>\n');
  res.write('    <h1>Node Ping</h1>\n');
  res.write('  </body>\n');
  res.write('</html>\n');
  res.end();
});
server.listen(8080);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');

var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.on('connection',function(client){
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  client.send(1);
  client.on('message',function(message){ client.send(1);  console.log( new Date$
  client.on('disconnect',function(){});
});
```

I'm very curious about this because it seems like my pings are pretty high(200-400ms round trip) on large vps boxes w/ dedicated resources both in california and new jersey.  (I'm on the east coast)  I'm betting theres just a lot of latency on the vps boxes b/c they're serving so much traffic?

The thing that gets me is that a regular ping from the linux terminal from the same client to the same server is 11ms on average a factor of 10 lower ... am I doing something wrong or is something slow with node.js/socket.io/websockets?

Comment: On what browser are you making your test?  Because when I made some test on Chrome the PING was around 40 ms and in Firefox 3.6.x it was around 350 ms.  I suppose the differences is mainly because Firefox 3.6 don't have natively support of websockets so the module "socket.io" will use Flash to create the connection between the server and the client.  And maybe the delay is cause by the time that it takes to the browser to communicate with the Flash with JavaScript.  On other hand when the browser supports websocket natively, he don't need to use Flash.

Comment: I'm working in one of the latest nightlies of chrome that supports the websockets transfer option.  I see what you're saying about the firefox/flash slowdown and haven't even started worrying about that yet.

Comment: After the most recent update of socket.io it seems that the server response times have plummeted down to ~10ms!

Answer (score 0):

**Read first —** Due to repeated questions why this is supposed to work, let me clarify a bit.

- The client callback function is *executed on the client,* which is why it has access to the closure, including the `start` variable containing the time stamp. This is [the ack() argument in socket.io.](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-emit-eventname-args-ack)
- The server naturally cannot call an arbitrary function on the client and access the function’s closure. But `socket.io` allows to define a callback funtion, which *appears to be executed* by the server, but this actually just passes the function arguments through the web socket, and the client then calls the callback.

What happens below (please do check the example code!):

1. Client stores current timestamp `1453213686429` in `start`
2. Client sends a `ping` event to the server and is waiting for an answer
3. Server responds to the ping event with “Please call your callback with empty arguments”
4. Client receives the response and calls `clientCallback` with empty arguments (Check the demo code if you want to see arguments)
5. `clientCallback` again takes the current timestamp *on the client*, e.g. `1453213686449`, and knows that `20 ms` have passed since it sent the request.

Imagine the druid *(client)* holding a stopwatch and pushing the button when the messenger *(event)* starts running, and pushing it again when the messenger arrives with his scroll *(function arguments)*. The druid then reads the scroll and adds the ingredient names to his potion recipe and brews the potion. *(callback)*

Okay, forget the previous paragraph, I guess you got the point.

---

Although the question has already been answered, here a short implementation for checking the RTT with `socket.io`:

### Client

```
var start = Date.now();
this.socket.emit( 'ping', function clientCallback() {
    console.log( 'Websocket RTT: ' + (Date.now() - start) + ' ms' );
} );
```

### Server

```
socket.on( 'ping', function ( fn ) {
    fn(); // Simply execute the callback on the client
} );
```

---

#### Demo Code

Demo code as node module: [socketIO-callback.tgz](http://granjow.net/uploads/code/socketIO-callback-0.0.1.tgz) Set it up and run it with

```
npm install
node callback.js
```

and then navigate to http://localhost:5060

Comment: Do you really think you can send a callback reference to the server as data and then have it execute on the server and somehow have that callback even have the ability to access a closure variable on the client?  This would not even come close to working.

Comment: he isn't passing a fn to be called but rather is calling the client-callback to say "i got it". its a socket.io thing.

Comment: I really like this approach. We're using the point at which the callback is executed as a place to check the time.

Comment: This will not work! You are taking date time on the client, which is the date time of pc/client, so if client sets its pc time to 01/01/2004 the ping would be more than ten years. Think of it.

Comment: @zazu Nope. Check the sample code. **The callback is executed on the client too.** Note that the server does not access the client, it just ask the client to please call the callback function with the arguments provided (if any). There is no magic in that.

Comment: But you set start variable on client side, so it would be the time set on client's device

Comment: @zazu I have extended the answer. Hope it answers the question now. Yes, it is *always* the time of the client device, but you just need to know the delta, does not matter if it is 2016 or 1883.

Comment: I can confirm this works, using it in production